# View Items permissions not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I want to assign anonymous access to list items. For that I have assigned anonymous access to web application and "Lists and libraries" permissions to site collection.

Now to assign permission to list I have written code:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(RootSiteUrl))
            {
                uint rootWebLanguage = site.RootWeb.Language;
                SPWebCollection allWebs = site.AllWebs;

                foreach (SPWeb currentWeb in allWebs)
                {
                    SPList list = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("listName");
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                        list.AllowEveryoneViewItems = true;
                        list.AnonymousPermMask = SPRights.ViewListItems;
                        //list.AnonymousPermMask64 = SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems;
                        list.Update();
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code will assign "View Items" permission to list but when I try to open list item in different browser then it is asking for login.

And if I will do same thing manually in that case I'm able to access list item anonymously.

It is not working using when I will try with coding.

Comment: Are you using custom master page or sharepoint default master page? because it might be happen it is asking login not for your list view but for some branding files which has not been published or not anonymously shared.

Comment: yes, I have custom master page. But it works when I try same steps manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(RootSiteUrl))
{
uint rootWebLanguage = site.RootWeb.Language;
SPWebCollection allWebs = site.AllWebs;

foreach (SPWeb currentWeb in allWebs)
{
    SPList list = currentWeb.Lists.TryGetList("listName");
    if (list != null)
    {
          if (!list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments)
    {
        list.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
    }                    
    SPBasePermissions sPBasePermissions = SPBasePermissions.EmptyMask;
    SPBasePermissions basePermissions = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(SPRoleType.Guest).BasePermissions;
    {
        sPBasePermissions = (basePermissions & ~(SPBasePermissions.BrowseUserInfo | SPBasePermissions.UseRemoteAPIs));
        sPBasePermissions |= (SPBasePermissions.ViewListItems | SPBasePermissions.OpenItems | SPBasePermissions.ViewVersions | SPBasePermissions.Open);
    }
    list.AnonymousPermMask64 = sPBasePermissions;
    list.Update();
    }
}
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much kalpesh vaghela......you code works for me.

Comment: Hello Kalpesh, I need you help. I have given anonymous permission to pages library. I'm able to access my all page. But I'm not able to access one page which is created from page layout. So, can you please help me that how can I access my page which is created from page layout anonymously?

Comment: are you using custom page layout or sharepoint OOTB page layout?

Comment: I'm using custom pagelayout.

Comment: Then first you should check like whether page layout is published, if you are loading scripts,images,styles in your page layout then those all should be published at least one time

Comment: I have checked all page layouts, images, styles, etc. published.

Comment: Is there any customization part is added in page layout like user control,web part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24496/discussion-between-kalpesh-vaghela-and-trimantra-software-solution).

Comment: Hello every one, I have assigned access to my lists which are used in my page layout. But problem is that when I try to get data from client object model (javascript) it will ask for authentication though list have anonymous access. I'm able to access lists anonymously.